# Renaming files: changing

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, file-rename, batch-rename, mv

## Problem

Given a directory with a large set of files using a spacer characters, here `-`, how can they all be changed to use another spacer character, for example `=`?

## Examples

`run-script-one.sh` → `run=script=one.sh`

`build-object-a.sh` → `build=object=a.sh`

`load-file-alpha.sh` → `load=file=alpha.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `prename` (Perl's standalone rename command):

```
prename -n 's/-/=/g' *.sh
```

Output:

```
build-object-a.sh renamed as build=object=a.sh
load-file-alpha.sh renamed as load=file=alpha.sh
run-script-one.sh renamed as run=script=one.sh
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n` (no action option).

---

If `prename` is not available:

```
for i in *.sh; do echo mv -v "$i" "${i//-/=}"; done
```

Remove `echo` if everything looks fine.

Comment: @dantopa Which OS are you using?

Comment: @dantopa: `for i in *.sh; do echo mv -v "$i"  "${i//-/=}"; done` Remove `echo` if everything looks fine.

Comment: @Cyrus, why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @Cyrus: Very elegant. Thanks for the extra effort.